# Can I check the JNI version from UNIX shell?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, version

How can I check which version of JNI I / user is currently using ? Is there any command that i directly execute on the shell prompt ?

Comment: was my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know of a way from the shell. You could just open up the jni.h file and see the version or if you want to do it through a program, something like

```
#ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_4  
printf("Version is 1.4 \n");
#endif
```

You can also use the JNI function `jint GetVersion(JNIEnv *env);`

Comment: for `jint GetVersion(JNIEnv *env)` gives me a big nunber !

Comment: @ program-o-steve :Does that number correspond to some thing here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23717.

Answer (score 1):

For people wondering, write the number returned by GetVersion out in hex to easily interpret its meaning.